# How do I assign comma separated values from an Inputbox to variables in VBA?

Tags: vba

The code is to assign values in the array created by the inputbox into variables created based on the number of comma-separated values in the array. i.e. if 5 comma-separated values (1,2,3,4,5) are entered in the Inputbox the code create 5 variables input1, input2 etc. and assign values from the input.

I have tried the following code and it is returning a "subscript out of range" error at input(v) = u

```
Sub test3()
    Dim strEntries As String, v As Long, item As Variant, inputArray() As String, u As Variant, input() As String
    strEntries = Application.InputBox("Enter multiple comma separated values. ", "Entries", Type:=2)
    If strEntries = "False" Then Exit Sub   'User canceled
    v = 0
    inputArray = Split(strEntries, ",")
    For Each u In inputArray
        Debug.Print u
        For v = LBound(inputArray) To UBound(inputArray)
            input(v) = u
            Next v
        v = v + 1
        Debug.Print "count =" & v
        
    Next u
End Sub
```

Comment: isn't that what InputArray is?  InputArray(0), InputArray(1), and so on?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited my previous comment with more details of what I am trying to do.

Comment: You do not need the loops at all. Split puts the items in the array.  You just need to refer to them as inputarray(0), inputarray(1), and so on to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

All that you appear to need is:

```
Sub test3()

    Dim strEntries As String, v As Long, item As Variant, inputArray() As String, u As Variant

    strEntries = Application.InputBox("Enter multiple comma separated values. ", "Entries", Type:=2)
    If strEntries = "False" Then Exit Sub   'User canceled
    inputArray = Split(strEntries, ",")
    For v = LBound(inputArray) To UBound(inputArray)
        Debug.Print inputArray(v)
    Next v
    Debug.Print "count = " & (UBound(inputArray) + 1)

End Sub
```

The remaining loop is just there for your debug.

The reason that your original code is falling over is because you've created input() as a dynamic array and never given it any dimensions - whereas Split() automatically dimensions inputArray for you.

Remember also that VBA arrays are 0-based by default (hence why I'm adding 1 to the UBound to get your Count).